# How to initialise a custom splash screen before loading tab bar controller in storyboard?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitabbarcontroller, splash-screen

I have an application in which i have a custom splash view controller and then the tab bar controller comes. Currently i have set the tab bar controller as the initial view controller . But i want the splash view controller appears first and then the tab bar controller . Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of PushView Controller Use presentViewController
Try this Code

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

   _ = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(2.1, target: self, selector: #selector(Splash.someSelector), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

func someSelector() {
    let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc : TabBarCotroller = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TabBarCotroller") as! TabBarCotroller

    let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
    self.present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

First of all in storyboard make custom class view controller as `Initial view controller`. And after that push `tabbar` controller to current `navigation controller`.

```
let tabBar = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("tabBarViewController") as! UITabBarController tabBarVC.selectedIndex = 0
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(tabBar, animated: true)
```

Comment: A better version of this:  `var navigationController: UINavigationController?` (call instance of navigationController)       `let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let tabBarViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabBarViewController") as! TabBarViewController
        tabBarViewController.selectedIndex = 0
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(tabBarViewController, animated: true)`

Answer (score 1):

@Amelia frensheo Something like that:

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
appDelegate.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
appDelegate.window.rootViewController = [[SplashViewCtr alloc] init];
appDelegate.window.rootViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
[appDelegate.window makeKeyAndVisible]; 
UITabBarController *rootViewCtrl = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
```

**The first way**

```
[appDelegate.window.rootViewController presentViewController:rootViewCtrl animated:YES completion:nil];
```

**The second way**

```
[UIView transitionFromView:window.rootViewController.view toView:rootViewCtrl.view duration:0.5 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        appDelegate.window.rootViewController = rootViewCtrl.view;
 }];
```

Comment: The question is tagged "swift".

Answer (score 0):

You can play the video of 5 sec while you push in tabcontroller's `viewWillAppear`.

Also you can add one more controller in between tabcontroller so your splash controller will be rootviewcontroller.

Answer (score 0):

You first need set your splash view controller as a rootViewController and after set `modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;`to rootViewController and present your tabviewcontroller or change a rootViewController

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this thing in this way,

First of all in storyboard make custom class view controller as Initial view controller .And after that push tabbar controller to current navigation controller.

```
let tabBarVC = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("tabBarViewController") as! UITabBarController
tabBarVC.selectedIndex = 0
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(tabBarVC, animated: true)
```

Try this it may help you.